# Buildah/podman usage for adding the annotations to the multi-arch manifest

Tags: containers, podman, buildah

Past few days I have been struggling with the multi-arch manifest annotation.
I use buildah/podman for creating my images, but I cannot discover a way how to add the common org.opencontainers.image.description annotation to the manifest defining multi-arch images.

In general, I build my images by using the following commands sequence:

```
# Build all arch. images
#
buildah bud --platform linux/amd64 -f Dockerfile --format oci --tls-verify=true -t debian-gcc:gcc_bullseye-linuxamd64 /home/runner/work/docker-images/docker-images
buildah bud --platform linux/arm64 -f Dockerfile --format oci --tls-verify=true -t debian-gcc:gcc_bullseye-linuxarm64 /home/runner/work/docker-images/docker-images

# Create a manifest and add all arch. images there.
#
buildah manifest create debian-gcc:gcc_bullseye
buildah manifest add debian-gcc:gcc_bullseye debian-gcc:gcc_bullseye-linuxamd64
buildah manifest add debian-gcc:gcc_bullseye debian-gcc:gcc_bullseye-linuxarm64

# Inspect the manifest
#
podman manifest inspect debian-gcc:gcc_bullseye
```

Manifest contains the following:

```
{
    "schemaVersion": 2,
    "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json",
    "manifests": [
        {
            "mediaType": "application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json",
            "size": 500,
            "digest": "sha256:7dbefc31c7b5f7c4f67f18f92213daec8c48740d9533996363812de4385b9528",
            "platform": {
                "architecture": "amd64",
                "os": "linux"
            }
        },
        {
            "mediaType": "application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json",
            "size": 500,
            "digest": "sha256:968fc2d27179baa3e7f8c85c7657659c5c67807dcd002922edce1437d22645f9",
            "platform": {
                "architecture": "arm64",
                "os": "linux"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to add an annotation for this manifest, but I have always failed so far.

The expected result would be:

```
{
    "schemaVersion": 2,
    "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json",
    "manifests": [
        {
            "mediaType": "application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json",
            "size": 500,
            "digest": "sha256:7dbefc31c7b5f7c4f67f18f92213daec8c48740d9533996363812de4385b9528",
            "platform": {
                "architecture": "amd64",
                "os": "linux"
            }
        },
        {
            "mediaType": "application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json",
            "size": 500,
            "digest": "sha256:968fc2d27179baa3e7f8c85c7657659c5c67807dcd002922edce1437d22645f9",
            "platform": {
                "architecture": "arm64",
                "os": "linux"
            }
        }
    ],
  "annotations": {
    "org.opencontainers.image.description: "My description ..."
  }
}
```

I was trying to use the [buildah-manifest-annotate](https://github.com/containers/buildah/blob/main/docs/buildah-manifest-annotate.1.md) without a success.

```
buildah manifest annotate --annotation org.opencontainers.image.description="My description ..." debian-gcc:gcc_bullseye debian-gcc:gcc_bullseye
```

I would say the main reason why this is failing is the fact that the manifest ["vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json"](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/manifest-v2-2/) cannot contain annotation per specification, however, the index ["vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json"](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/main/image-index.md) can.

The motivation for this is to have a proper description for multi-arch images in the github packages or the quay repository.

[image]

So, in summary, the question is how can I annotate the multi-arch image by using the `podman` or `buildah`?

I appreciate any help putting me back on the right track.